# CSS3DRenderer disable scaling

Tags: javascript, three.js

see my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599154/transform-html-elements-in-conjunction-with-orbitcontrols-so-that-they-appear-to) for reference to what I am trying to achieve

**TL;DR:**
I am trying to get HTML elements to rotate in conjunction with `OrbitControls` to make it seem as if these HTML elements are stuck to the globe and move with it. (think map markers on a 3D earth above certain countries)

I achieved this almost successfully using the THREE.js `CSS3DRenderer`, and was able to get the HTML elements to stick to a location on my 3D globe with a lat/long calculation and rotate with the globe when `OrbitControls` are used.

**The problem**

The only issue I am having is that the HTML elements are scaling proportionate to how close/far they are from the camera. Usually I assume this would be the desired effect to help the sense of getting closer/further, but the scaling is causing me not to be able to size my HTML elements correctly and consistently, and also causing text and SVGs inside the elements to blur/become pixelated

**What I want**

I am looking for a way to turn off this scaling so that the HTML elements still transform in every other way, but stay the same size (i.e. scale(1, 1, 1) or their original scale) no matter where they are in the 3D renderer created by `CSS3DRenderer`.

I assume I will have to edit the CSS3DRenderer.js code for this, but I have absolutely no idea where to start and I cannot find any information anywhere else.

Thanks.

**Some of my code:**

Creating the `CSS3DRenderer`

```
//CSS3D Renderer
rendererHTML = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
rendererHTML.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
rendererHTML.domElement.classList.add('CSS3D-container');

containerHTML = document.querySelector('.globe__container');
containerHTML.appendChild(rendererHTML.domElement);
```

Resizing function (called on window resize event)

```
HEIGHT = sizeControlElem.getBoundingClientRect().width;
WIDTH = sizeControlElem.getBoundingClientRect().width;

renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
rendererHTML.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

Creating the CSS3DSprite objects from `<li>` elements in the HTML and setting their initial positions on the globe

```
for (let key in this.locationsObject) {

    _this.locationsObject[key].coordinates = calcPosFromLatLonRad(this.locationsObject[key].lat, this.locationsObject[key].long, 300);

    let CSS3D_Object = new THREE.CSS3DSprite(_this.locationsObject[key].element);
    CSS3D_Object.position.set(_this.locationsObject[key].coordinates[0], _this.locationsObject[key].coordinates[1], _this.locationsObject[key].coordinates[2]);
    CSS3D_Object.receiveShadow = false;
    CSS3D_Object.castShadow = false;
    sceneHTML.add(CSS3D_Object);

    _this.locationsObject[key].CSS_Object = CSS3D_Object;

    console.info(CSS3D_Object);
}
```

You can see some more of my code in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599154/transform-html-elements-in-conjunction-with-orbitcontrols-so-that-they-appear-to)

Comment: I can't see your code, but I'm assuming you're not scaling resolution as well eg, in CanvasRenderer resolution is connected to canvas width and height.

Comment: @Zydnar I am scaling the CSS3D canvas the same exact way I am scaling the WebGL canvas e.g. with this line in a window resize function: `rendererHTML.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);`, `rendererHTML` being the CSS3DRenderer

Comment: I'm not up to date with the newest threeJS but in examples, under CSS3D section one of exaples use this on resize: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/1cbcaab0b8c80cd66b5812881597529f9ebd19c0/examples/css3d_molecules.html#L518

Comment: @Zydnar I am already doing that. My issue is with the individual `CSS3DSprite` objects scaling, not the canvas

Comment: I'm just guessing without your code.

Comment: @Zydnar I have added some of the code I think related to the question. You can find more of it in the question I linked to twice

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve? Do you want to disable distance scaling altogether, or are you trying to avoid blurring/pixellation due to HTMLElements getting too close to the camera? You could fix the latter without having to disable scaling based on distance.

Comment: @Marquizzo I want to disable distance scaling as well as fixing the blurriness. The desired effect is to have 2 different sizes for the markers (set with a css class i.e. "hidden"). This css hidden class is only added once the markers are moved "behind" the globe i.e. a marker's distance from the camera is greater that the distance of the edge of the globe from the camera. It would be useful to also know how to fix blurriness without disabled scaling but the most important thing is disabling scaling.

Comment: @Marquizzo Would really appreciate an answer on this if you know how to disable the scaling! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the easiest solution to my question is simply to use the `CSS2DRenderer` instead of the `CSS3DRenderer`.

It essentially does the same thing but only transforms the HTML element with `translate`, and does not `rotate` or `scale` it, meaning you can modify the size of the HTML elements freely using CSS width and size etc... which is what I wanted to do.

It is implemented in the exact same way, the only thing I had to change in my code was replacing `CSS3DSprite` with `CSS2DObject`.

Read more about `CSS2DRenderer` [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/renderers/CSS2DRenderer).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to stop the scaling is by projecting the 3D positions to 2D with the `Vector3.project()` method. Take a look at the code sample below, I commented the key points in the JavaScript code, but a quick explanation is this:

1. Copy the 3D position where you want the hotspot into a new vector.
2. Use `vector.project(camera)` to translate that 3D point to 2D coordinates.
3. Transform the range of 2D coords from [-1, 1] to [0, window.width]
4. Apply these coordinates via CSS to your hotspot.

Bonus: You can still use the `.z` attribute of the 2D vector to determine if it's within the camera's frustum or not.

```js
var camera, controls, scene, renderer;

// This array will hold all positions in 3D space
var posArray3D = [];

// This array will hold all hotspot DIVs
var divArray = [];

// Create temp vector to reuse on loops
var tempVec = new THREE.Vector3();

init();
animate();

function init() {

 scene = new THREE.Scene();
 scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xcccccc );

 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
 renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
 renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
 document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 3000 );
 camera.position.set( 400, 200, 0 );

 // controls
 controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

 controls.enableDamping = true;
 controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;

 controls.screenSpacePanning = false;

 controls.minDistance = 100;
 controls.maxDistance = 500;

 controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;



 // world
 var geometry = new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry( 0, 10, 30, 4, 1 );
 var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, flatShading: true } );

 // This is where all hotspot DIVs will go
 var hotspotBox = document.getElementById("hotspotBox");

 for ( var i = 0; i < 100; i ++ ) {
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  mesh.position.x = Math.random() * 1600 - 800;
  mesh.position.y = 0;
  mesh.position.z = Math.random() * 1600 - 800;
  mesh.updateMatrix();
  mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
  scene.add( mesh );

  // Populate array of 3D positions
  posArray3D.push(mesh.position);

  // Create 'hotspot' DIV, and place within 'hotspotBox' holder
  divArray.push(document.createElement("div"));
  divArray[i].classList.add("hotspot");
  hotspotBox.appendChild(divArray[i]);
 }


 // lights
 var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
 light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
 scene.add( light );

 var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x002288 );
 light.position.set( - 1, - 1, - 1 );
 scene.add( light );

 var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
 scene.add( light );

 window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function onWindowResize() {

 camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

 renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

// Loops through all divs and updates their positions based on the camera
function updateDivs() {
 var vectorScreen = new THREE.Vector3();

 // Loop through all positions
 for (var i = 0; i < posArray3D.length; i ++) {
  vectorScreen.copy(worldToScreen(posArray3D[i], camera));

  // Update CSS attributes of each DIV
  divArray[i].style.transform = "translate(" + vectorScreen.x + "px, " + vectorScreen.y + "px)";

  // Checks for depth, hides if it's behind the camera
  if(vectorScreen.z <= 1) {
   divArray[i].style.display = "block";
  } else {
   divArray[i].style.display = "none";
  }
 }
}

// Projects 3D coordinates into 2D space 
function worldToScreen(_position, _cam) {
 tempVec.copy(_position);

 tempVec.project(_cam);

 // Converts range from [-1, 1] to [0, windowWidth]
 tempVec.x = (   tempVec.x + 1 ) * window.innerWidth  / 2;
 tempVec.y = ( - tempVec.y + 1 ) * window.innerHeight / 2;

 return tempVec;
}

function animate() {

 requestAnimationFrame( animate );

 controls.update();
 updateDivs();

 render();

}

function render() {

 renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```css
body {
 color: #000;
 font-family:Monospace;
 font-size:13px;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight: bold;

 background-color: #fff;
 margin: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
/*hotspotBox holds all .hotspots It's placed on top of WebGL canvas*/
#hotspotBox{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 border: 1px dashed #f90;
 pointer-events: none;
}
/*100 hotspots to be placed within #hotspotBox */
.hotspot {
 background: #f90;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
 pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="hotspotBox"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/99/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```